# Delete route isn't working in my admin area using form tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not sure why my form is giving me an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"delete", :area=>"admin", :controller=>"admin/users", :id=>"10"}
```

The URL is:

```
admin/users/delete_confirmation/10
```

My form tag looks like:

```
<%= form_tag(area: "admin", controller: "users", action: "delete") do %>
```

When I run rake routes I can see the route:

```
admin_user DELETE /admin/users/:id(.:format)                                        admin/users#destroy

admin_user_delete_confirmation GET    /admin/users/delete_confirmation/:id(.:format)                    admin/users#delete_confirmation
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is 'delete_confirmation' coming from in the URL? it looks like it shouldn't be there given the definition of your route.

Comment: @jaydel I pasted the wrong route, I edited it.